# How to resolve MySQL Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value?

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to update 2 different tables with an update query as shown below

```
UPDATE  db1.table1 a, db2.table1 b 
SET       b.firstname  =  a.firstname,
          b.lastname   =  a.lastname,
          b.address    =  a.address,
          b.state      =  a.state,
          b.city       =  a.city,
          b.zip        =  a.zip             

WHERE a.stud_id=b.stud_id AND a.firstname IS NOT NULL AND b.firstname IS NULL
          AND str_to_date(a.joindate,'%m/%d/%Y') >= str_to_date('02/01/2012','%m/%d/%Y');
```

but when i tried to execute this query, MySQL kept throwing the following error

```
Error Code: 1292. Truncated incorrect DOUBLE value: 'CROUGH0000'
```

Though i've found much similar posts in stackoverflow, i couldn't find the exact solution to this problem.

Need some help. Thanks in advance

---

EDIT : Datatypes of each column are as follows

```
              b.firstname(varchar(25))  =  a.firstname(varchar(52)),
              b.lastname(varchar(25))   =  a.lastname(varchar(35)),
              b.address(varchar(40))    =  a.address(varchar(50)),
              b.state(char(2))      =  a.state(char(2)),
              b.city(varchar(25))       =  a.city(varchar(25)),
              b.zip(varchar(11))        =  a.zip(varchar(11))
```

Comment: Please add the data types for `stud_id` and `joindate` in each table. Also, please tell us where the value `'CROUGH0000'` comes from? Is that stud_id?

Answer (score 2):

If all those columns are varchar (as you've stated above) then the problem must be with `a.stud_id=b.stud_id`.

Check your data types in both tables a and b. Something has to be a DOUBLE or MySQL wouldn't be complaining about it.

Comment: @D Mac  a.stud_id and b.stud_id have the same datatypes

Comment: Then something that you've stated above is wrong. In my experience, MySQL doesn't throw capricious error messages - there is something in there with a datatype of DOUBLE and that's where your problem is. Find it, and you'll know what to fix.

Comment: @DMac Not necessarily, apparently. [Cf.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16068993/error-code-1292-truncated-incorrect-double-value-mysql#comment22935664_16068993)

Answer (score 2):

For me this error was showing because I was using 'and' to update 2 Queries instead of a 'comma'.

This snippet shows the error:

```
UPDATE employees 
SET 
lastname = 'Hill'and
email = 'mary.hill@classicmodelcars.com'
WHERE
employeeNumber = 1056;
```

This snippet shows the correction:

```
UPDATE employees 
SET 
lastname = 'Hill',
email = 'mary.hill@classicmodelcars.com'
WHERE
employeeNumber = 1056;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that `joindate` column contains a String value that is not String-Date.

To check that, if possible, I propose to test following SQL command

```
UPDATE db1.table1 a
      ,db2.table1 b 
SET b.firstname = b.firstname,
WHERE a.stud_id=b.stud_id 
  AND a.firstname IS NOT NULL 
  AND b.firstname IS NULL;
```

If this work, nothing has been changed but you know that your issue is linked to `joindate` field or `str_to_date` function.

Caution: b.firstname is assigned to same value -> nothing is changed

Answer (score 0):

I had an unexpected issue where I was comparing data types properly in the where clause but still got the same exception.

I was having this exception just because I had a **scheduled event** on the table which I was trying to update that was clearly comparing different types of fields in the where clause. After fixing that issue everything worked properly.